# HTTP server in Java with long time reposnse

Tags: java, server

I want to write a HTTP server with a long time response.
I prepared a loop:

```
    serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 8000));

    while (serverSocketChannel.isOpen()) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Waiting...");
            SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
            System.out.println("The new connection is open ;)");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(ServerHttp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I want to catch new connection from a user's browser, put it into a list, and then another thread will take it and will parse it.
But I have problem on the beginning: the code above is freezing in the method *serverSocketChannel.accept()*.

When I add *socketChannel.close()* everything is working correctly, but I don't want to close the connection in this place, because I need a long time response.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the javadoc for [ServerSocketChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html#accept%28%29):

"If this channel is in *non-blocking mode* then this method will immediately return null if there are no pending connections. *Otherwise it will block indefinitely until a new connection is available or an I/O error occurs*."

This seems to describe the "freezing" you are experiencing.

You can open your ServerSocketChannel in non-blocking mode:

```
serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
```

Comment: the result is the same. The program is freezing like in the first example